# CSS <link> href loses leading slash, utilizing SilverStripe

Tags: php, css, hyperlink, doctype, silverstripe

I am using SilverStripe as a CMS (http://www.silverstripe.com/services/why-choose-us/open-source-cms/) instead of Joomla or Drupal, and it has been a great experience for the most part so far. This problem however, is so strange that I am not even sure that SilverStripe has anything to do with it. Basically, links to CSS files that are set in a template are losing their leading slash when the markup is output to the browser. Obviously this can be very problematic.

This is the head section in the relevant template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <% base_tag %>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=720, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>$Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
        href="/framework/admin/thirdparty/jquery-notice/jquery.notice.css?m=1342411326" />
</head>
```

The links are actually generated into the template dynamically, but I put this one link in myself to isolate the issue. Even manually added into the template, the link markup will end up with href="framework/admin/thirdparty/jquery-notice/jquery.notice.css?m=1342411326", the original link minus the leading forward-slash,/. Does anyone have an idea how this might happen? Doesn't matter if I'm in Chrome, Safari or Firefox, they all behave the same.

I have noticed I can "fix" the issue by breaking the whole document. If I add a character before `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the href on the css link is pointing at the root again with the leading slash. Is this because of the doctype, the base tag, or some strange combination of the two?

One of the stranger issues I've come across...

Comment: How are you including your CSS files? From the PHP classes using `Requirements::themedCSS()`? Or using special `themedCSS()` template tags? Check the `<% base_tag %>` call you have in the template. This SS tag will output something like `<base href="http://example.com/" />`. As far as I know, this is a necessary requirement for SilverStripe and cannot be removed without "unexpected" behavior.

Comment: The base tag looks to be building properly: `<base href="http://www.brooksransom.com/"><!--[if lte IE 6]></base><![endif]-->`. My local dev site outputs the same structure for base, but it works. And as for your question, the SS CMS brings in JS and CSS in LeftAndMain::init(), with this call: `Requirements::css(FRAMEWORK_ADMIN_DIR . '/thirdparty/jquery-notice/jquery.notice.css');` for each of the files.

Comment: http://www.brooksransom.com/ is not a SilverStripe site, correct? Do you have a dev subdomain, or something similar? If so, that could be your problem. I understand not wanting to share your URL, but make sure that the actual site URL corresponds to what is generated in the `<BASE>` tag. Also, the links are not supposed to have a leading `/` - the `<BASE>` tag takes care of this. All URLs generated by SilverStrip are relative.

Answer (score 2):

By default, SilverStripe leaves off the leading slash on purpose, and uses the base tag to ensure that the links point to the right place.  The reason that this was done was to make it easier to build sites that would still work if the site is run in a sub-URL, so that a development site, for example, might be at `http://localhost/mysite/`.

This is the reason why everything goes to hell in a handbasket if you get rid of the base tag - SilverStripe was built expecting it to be there.

However, it shouldn't be stripping off leading slashes on URLs.  The most likely thing that would be doing this is the `ContentNegotiator` class, and that would lead to different behaviour if you mucked with the doctype.

It used to be on by default but in 2.4 and 3.0 it should be off by default.  What version of SilverStripe are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try appending an extra `/` at location from where the link is generated.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [`base`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag?

If this won't work, you can try putting there whole link eg. `http://website.com/framework...`

Comment: Base tag is in there, and taking it out causes many other problems.

Comment: Possibly. I would have to rewrite or extend some of the SilverStripe code to accomplish this, and generally it's best to avoid this because it can cause problem if they ever need to use an SSL connection (https). This can be overcome of course. Will try and report back.

Comment: I should delete this post, as the problem is different than I've explained it. The CSS files are a bit of a red-herring. Because the base tag is in there, the css files are getting read correctly even though they look to have relative paths. The CMS still doesn't load the main panel at all, and for some reason breaking the document by putting a character before the DOCTYPE tag "fixes" it.